# python TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on this code

A certain university classifies students according to credits earned. A student with less than 30 hours is a Freshman. At least 30 credits are required to be a Sophomore, 60 to be a Junior, and 90 to be a Senior. Write a program that calculates class standing from the number of credits earned with the following specifications:

1. Write a function named determineStatus() that prompts the user for how many credits they have earned and uses a decision structure (if, else, etc.) to determine the class standing of the student. The function should display the standing to the student (85 points).
2. If the user tries to enter a negative value, the program should alert the user that negative numbers are not allowed (5 points).
3. Write a main() function that calls the determineStatus() function (5 points).

   ```
   def determineStatus():

       credits= -1;
       while(credits<0 ):

           credits=int(input("enter number of credits earned: "))

           if(credits<0):

               print("ALERT: you entered negative credit. Pls try again")


           if(credits<30):

               print("A Freshman!")

           elif(credits>30 and credits<60):

               print("A Sophomore!")

           elif(credits>60 and credits<90):

               print("A Junior")

           else:

               print("A Senior")





   def main():

       determineStatus()

       main()
   ```

Comment: Could you please share the full stack trace and error message with line number.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of the code and take note of how code blocks work? When you edit, hit the ? on the upper right, select "code", and see how it works.

Comment: Note also that there is nothing called `_Printer` in your code. I see no way that this code produces that error.

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code. If the number is negative, it will still print "You're a freshman". If the number is 30 ou 60, it will print "A senior"